# Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found

Tags: laravel, routes, http-status-code-404, laravel-5.5

I have the following web route :

```
Route::get('/Observation/{type}/list/{status}', 'ObservationController@index')->name('list_observation');
```

When i open that route from following url :

[localhost:8088/hse/public/Observation/status/list/all](http://localhost:8088/hse/public/Observation/status/list/all)

Error showing :

```
  Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

It was working before then suddenly this issue occurred .

Comment: Type in terminal:`php artisan route:list` inside your project directory, then you can see how to use your route. I tried yours here and it worked fine with `project.dev/Observation/status/list/all` (project.dev come from valet)

Comment: @Matz C:\xampp\htdocs\hse>php artisan route:list
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Call to a member function parameter() on null
,,, the other routes is working fine

Comment: why do you use public in the url? your route should be after `hse`

Comment: @Onix Because i am not using a laravel homestead , i am using local host xampp , and in Laravel by default the controllers and views are accessed from main folder /public.

Comment: Yes, public is correct. So if `php artisan route:list` return an error, you have somewhere a syntax error

Comment: @Matz , i checked the code in files that i am currently working on in PhpStorm, there is not error showing here in IDE , however , if there is syntax error in coding, how the other routes is working , or if there is a syntax error , it it possible that laravel return like that error ?

Comment: Laravel returns an error if in some classes you use in your routes is an error

Comment: please replace `/Observation/{type}/list/{status}` with `/observation/{type}/list/{status}` and tell me if worked

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the parameter name {status} to {value} .
And in controller changed the following :

From protected $status ; to  protected $value ;

```
 __construct() {

 $this->value = Route::current()->parameter('value');
}
```

I think the issue was because i am passing an Model name status with variable $status as argument for index() method

```
public function index(status $status)
```

And the model name is the same of the class protected status variable name .